# What does "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'" mean?

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

I am trying to find the equal and adjacent values in a 2d vector and group them together.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < r; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < k; j++){
            temp.clear();
            cout << table.at(i).at(j);
            if(table.at(i).at(j) == 1){
                groupFind(table, i, j);
                grupet.push_back(temp);
            }
        }
    }

...

void groupFind(vector<vector<int> > table, int x, int y){
    table.at(x).at(y) = 2;
    temp.push_back(make_pair(x, y));
    if(table.at(x+1).at(y) == 1 && in_bound(x+1, y)) groupFind(table, x+1, y);
    if(table.at(x-1).at(y) == 1 && in_bound(x-1, y)) groupFind(table, x-1, y);
    if(table.at(x).at(y+1) == 1 && in_bound(x, y+1)) groupFind(table, x, y+1);
    if(table.at(x).at(y-1) == 1 && in_bound(x, y-1)) groupFind(table, x, y-1);
}

bool in_bound(int x, int y){
    if(x < 0 || x > r - 1|| y < 0 || y > k - 1){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It only iterates over the first row and then stops.

Comment: It means one of the `at` calls was passed an index outside the valid range for the container.

Comment: the arguments of && are evaluated in left to right order, so if first one throws or is false then the second argument is never evaluated. IOW checking in_bound in second argument of && is too late.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you do have to make sure that the `at` functions that you called are in bounds.
The main problem should be here:

```
if(table.at(x+1).at(y) == 1 && in_bound(x+1, y)) groupFind(table, x+1, y);
```

You put the `in_bound` function after the `table.at(x+1).at(y) == 1`, so your compiler first checks that part instead of the in_bound. So, if `x + 1` is out of bounds, C++ doesn't check your `in_bound` function first. That causes your out-of-range problem.